# Why isn't $\zeta(3) = 2^3\pi ^{3-1}\sin\left( \frac{\pi 3}{2}\right)\Gamma(1-3)\zeta(1-3) = 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, riemann-zeta

The zeta function (for $\Re(s)>1$) is given by the definition:

1. $\zeta(s) = \sum _{n=1}^{\infty} \left [\frac{1}{n^s} \right]$

The zeta function also can be given by the following functional equation:

2. $\zeta(s) = 2^s\pi ^{s-1}\sin\left( \frac{\pi s}{2}\right)\Gamma(1-s)\zeta(1-s)$

Using the above functional equation, we also know than for all negative even integers (i.e. $s=-2, -4, -6...$) the zeta function has trivial zeroes i.e.
$\zeta(-2) = 0$, $\zeta(-4) = 0$, $\zeta(-6) = 0$ and so on.

Substituting $s=3$ in the functional equation we have:

a. $\zeta(3) = \sum _{n=1}^{\infty} \left [\frac{1}{n^3} \right]$

b. $\zeta(3) = 2^3\pi ^{3-1}\sin\left( \frac{\pi 3}{2}\right)\Gamma(1-3)\zeta(1-3)$

Since, $\zeta(1-3)=\zeta(-2)=0$,  using this in the R.H.S of the functional equation (b.) seems to state that $\zeta(3) = 0$. But, using (a.) we know that the $\zeta(3)$ is convergent but not equal to zero.

So, these two values are different. What is it that I am missing in the functional definition and where is the discrepancy?

P.S. I am from a C.S. background and a beginner in analysis still trying to learn.

Comment: "The zeta function is given by the definition: 1. $\zeta(s) = \sum _{n=1}^{\infty} \left [\frac{1}{n^s} \right]$" For the record, this is the definition of $\zeta(s)$ **only when $\Re s>1$**.

Comment: Yes. I was a bit loose with the definition.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The function $\Gamma$ has a pole at every non-positive integer. The pole of $\Gamma$ at $-2$ "cancels out" the zero of $\zeta$ at $-2$ since they are both simple.